# Mongodb, cyrillic text, errors

Tags: mongodb, cyrillic

I am using mongodb to store some cyrillic text from some feed rss News.
The text is correctly stored but when I try to search a document with a simple find function:

```
db.test.find({'title':'РФ заняла первое место в мире по числу полицейских на душу населения / Инфографика'});
```

It returns me a "`buffer too small`" error.

and when I run

```
db.test.find({'title':'Прибыль из воздуха?'})
```

It returns me this error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (shell):1

What does it mean? Something wrong with text encoding or what?

Comment: You have to buy a faster buffer. \*scnr\* :-)

Comment: If i a try to change the query in db.News.find({'title':'РФ '}); it returns a Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (shell):1 .
How is it possible?

Comment: I don't reproduce this with mongod 2.6/mongo 2.6. What version are you using? Can you post the entire document? Can you post the entire error message?